# For any $p,q\in E$, $|f(p)-f(q)|<\epsilon$, how to prove $f$ is bounded on $E$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:E\to \Bbb R$, where $E$ is an arbitrary metric space, and for any $p,q\in E$, $|f(p)-f(q)|<\epsilon$ for some positive number $\epsilon$.

I want to show that $f(E)$ is bounded in $\Bbb R$, but I have no idea to show that $f(E)\subset B(0,M)$ for some $M>0$ is large.

Could someone give me some advice to find the upper bounded of $|f|$ on $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $q\in E$. Then for any $p \in E$, $|f(p)-f(q)|<\epsilon$. Can you use this to find an upper bound on $|f|$?

Comment: What if $|f(p)|=+\infty$?

Comment: $\pm\infty\notin\mathbb R$

Comment: Also if $|f(p)|=+\infty$, then $|f|$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $q$, then $f(q)=A$ is some constant functional value.

Now, $|f(p)|-|f(q)|\le |f(p)-f(q)| \lt \epsilon $
$\implies |f(p)|\lt |A|+\epsilon $ for all $p\in E$

Comment: $|f(p)-f(q)|<\epsilon$ means that $-\epsilon< f(p)-f(q)<\epsilon$. That is, $f(p)<A+\epsilon$ and $-f(p)<-A+\epsilon$. Hence $|f(p)|<|A|+\epsilon$. Your implication is not correct if $A<0$, because you could have $A+\epsilon < |f(p)|<|A|+\epsilon$.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut it doesn't matter whether $A$ is positive of negative, because I take absolute value of $A$ ,,and $|A|+\epsilon$ provide the bounds of $f$, as $-|A|-\epsilon \lt |f(p)| \lt |A|+\epsilon $.

Comment: Now, yes. ${}{}{}$